# How Exactly To Configure OpenSSL Fore Use With VC++?

Tags: c, visual-c++, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I am in the middle of a project ATM that requires the use of both AES and RSA encryption, and I have heard many times that OpenSSL is a good open source implementation of these algorithms. So I downloaded OpenSSL and I have never used an external library like this before, so I googled how to use it in VC++ since I couldn't figure it out; came across this guide: http://developer.covenanteyes.com/building-openssl-for-visual-studio/ . This is the only guide I could find that really pertained to my question, but I am having some trouble using it. I think it is made for an older version of OpenSSL. I am having problems when executing the command "ms\do_ms" (I am using Visual C++ 2010, same as the tutorial).

Using libraries is really something I have no idea how to use so I think it is quite possible I am completely over-complicating things somehow, so if someone could either help me use this tutorial or just tell me how I can use OpenSSL to have AES and RSA encryption in my project, I would really appreciate it. Thanks guys, I hope its just a small thing I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You also need perl for this. Install Active perl and then run configuration script.

After that run ms\do_ms and then modify your make file (in ms folder).

This link might help you: http://botsikas.blogspot.in/2012/10/building-openssl-on-windows.html

Comment: I did install Active perl, I got past that step. Where is the ms folder?

Comment: ms folder in inside OpenSSL folder.

Comment: When I run ms\do_ms, things seem to start off fine and then I get this same error twice: unable to open ssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory. Is there any other tutorial to doing this because I really have no experience as to what I am supposed to be editing here?